# JavaScript Twitter button code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I'm trying to display a twitter button, but the code for the twitter button is being displayed as a text link.  I've been trying to fix the problem, but it won't change back into a button.  What am I doing wrong?  Please help.

```
var i = 0;

var a;
var b;
var c;
var d;

function calculate() {

  console.log(1);
  var activity = $("#txtActivity").val();

  var days = parseInt( $("#txtDays").val(), 10);
  var hours = parseInt( $("#txtHours").val(), 10);
  var minutes = parseInt( $("#txtMinutes").val(), 10);
  var seconds = parseInt( $("#txtSeconds").val(), 10);

  var MoneyMadeDuringActivity = (days * 21464) + (hours * 2683) + (minutes * 44.72) + (seconds * 0.74);
  MoneyMadeDuringActivity = MoneyMadeDuringActivity.toFixed(2);

  if (isNaN(MoneyMadeDuringActivity)) {
    MoneyMadeDuringActivity = 0.00;
  }

  if (i < MoneyMadeDuringActivity) {
    if (a < MoneyMadeDuringActivity) { i = i + a; }
    if (b < MoneyMadeDuringActivity) { i = i + b; }
    if (c < MoneyMadeDuringActivity) { i = i + c; }
    if (d < MoneyMadeDuringActivity) { i = i + d; }
  } else if (i > MoneyMadeDuringActivity) {
    if (a < MoneyMadeDuringActivity) { i = i - a; }
    if (b < MoneyMadeDuringActivity) { i = i - b; }
    if (c < MoneyMadeDuringActivity) { i = i - c; }
    if (d < MoneyMadeDuringActivity) { i = i - d; }
  }

  $.getScript("http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");
  var twit_link = $('<a/>', {
    href : 'https://www.twitter.com/share',
    'class' : 'twitter-share-button',
    url : 'http://www.twitter.com/obamamakes',
    'data-count' : 'none',
    'data-via' : 'ObamaMakes',
    'data-text' : 'In the time it takes me to ' + activity + ', Barack Obama makes $' + i.toFixed(1)
  }).text('Tweet');

  $("#CalcOutput").html("In the time it takes me to <span class=\"num\">" + activity + "</span>,<br /> Barack Obama makes <span class=\"num\">" + "$" + i.toFixed(1) + "</span><br />");
  $("#CalcOutput").append( twit_link );
}

  $("#txtDays").focus(function() {
    $(this).val('');
  });
  $("#txtDays").keyup(function(event) {
    a = 2683;
    setInterval(calculate, 5);
  });

  $("#txtHours").focus(function(){
    $(this).val('');
  });
  $("#txtHours").keyup(function(event) {
    b = 670.75;
    setInterval(calculate, 5);
  });

  $("#txtMinutes").focus(function() {
    $(this).val('');
  });
  $("#txtMinutes").keyup(function(event) {
    c = 22.36;
    setInterval(calculate, 5);
  });

  $("#txtSeconds").focus(function(){
    $(this).val('');
  });
  $("#txtSeconds").keyup(function(event) {
    d = 0.37;
    setInterval(calculate, 5);
  });
```

Comment: Can you please strip out all the code not related to displaying the Twitter button? Reduce your test case to just the essentials and you'll have a much better chance of finding the issue: http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/

Answer (score 0):

you're missing css , in your script there you are setting a link with the class `twitter-share-button`  you need a style sheet that has that class in it.  You probably already know how to link a css sheet into HTML , but here is an example :  this goes in between `<head>`

```
 <link href="controls/ControlStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

EDIT:

make sure this is in your HTML like in the [Twitter Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button)

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

There are different `<script>` tag options depending on how you want the button to look, I would still try to incorporate that styling into yourown css on your own server if possible

Comment: I didn't have to include a stylesheet for my other twitter buttons though.  All I had to do was copy and paste javascript code.  For some reason some buttons aren't being displayed correctly.

Comment: if possible always use your own stylesheets instead of depending on other url's , I'll see if it can find it for you, and put it on your server

Answer (score 0):

In all of [Twitter's examples](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button), the loaded script comes after the `<a>` tag markup. It is possible since you are loading the script first that it might be executing immediately, instead of in response to the `DOMContentReady` event, and therefore not finding any buttons to create. Try including the script after the markup is appended. Or try using Twitter's non-jQuery code exactly.